# Umbraco 404 redirect not working for url with extensions like .html, .jpg, .asp

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, umbraco7

I have done the normal Umbraco 404 page setup changes. Urls like "/dsfd" works fine  but I when I do something like "/dfad.jpg" I get status 404 with server error **Resource not found**
Changes done so far:

1] umbracoSettings.config

```
    <errors>
  <error404>3231</error404>
  <!-- 
    The value for error pages can be:
    * A content item's integer ID   (example: 1234)
    * A content item's GUID ID      (example: 26C1D84F-C900-4D53-B167-E25CC489DAC8)
    * An XPath statement            (example: //errorPages[@nodeName='My cool error']
  -->
  <!--
    <error404>
        <errorPage culture="default">1</errorPage>
        <errorPage culture="en-US">200</errorPage>
    </error404>
   -->      
</errors>
```

2]web.config

```
 <customErrors mode="Off" />
```

And

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
```

This is a similar problem explained [Here In Umbraco Forum](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/extending-umbraco/13257-Get-Custom-Not-Found-Page-to-Return-404-Status-Code)